# iterating value over java 8

Tags: java, spring

I have the following code in Java 8

```
List<CategoryTranslation> categoriesTranslation = categoriesRepository.findByLanguageId(languageId);
List<CategoryDTO> categoryList = categoriesTranslation
.stream()
.map(x -> categoriesAdapter.category2DTO(x))                
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This works correctly , but I need to convert like this.

```
   List<CategoryTranslation> categoriesTranslation = categoriesRepository.findByLanguageId(languageId);
    List<CategoryDTO> categoryList = new ArrayList<CategoryDTO>();
   for (CategoryTranslation categoryTranslation : categoriesTranslation) {
                    CategoryDTO categoryDTO = categoriesAdapter.category2DTO(categoryTranslation);
                    categoryDTO.setTotal(categoryRepository.countTotalArticlesByCategory(categoryDTO.getCategoryId(), languageId));
                    categoryList.add(categoryDTO);
                }
```

I know that I could use the adapter but I don't like to use a JPA in Adapter.

Comment: FYI, you can replace `x -> categoriesAdapter.category2DTO(x)` with `categoriesAdapter::category2DTO`.

Comment: Yes , this work but as you could see I have the property setTotal ... how could I add this using java 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a method `categorty2DTOWithTotal(CategoryTranslation ct, Long? languiageId)`.
Otherwise you'd have to call `forEach`, but it's a terminating method so you couldn't group it into a list. In theory if setting total would result in sensible mapping, you could introduce a method which does that, but here it seems like a bit of a stretch.

```
void aMethod(Long? languageId) {
    List<CategoryTranslation> categoriesTranslation = categoriesRepository
        .findByLanguageId(languageId);
    List<CategoryDTO> categoryList = categoriesTranslation
        .stream()
        .map(x -> category2DTOWithTotal(x, languageId))                
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

CategoryDTO category2DTOWithTotal(CategoryTranslation ct, Long? languageId) {
    CategoryDTO categoryDTO = categoriesAdapter.category2DTO(categoryTranslation);
    categoryDTO.setTotal(
        categoryRepository.countTotalArticlesByCategory(
            categoryDTO.getCategoryId(), languageId
        )
    );
    return categoryDTO;
}
```

Or, you could set total later:

```
void aMethod(Long? languageId) {
    List<CategoryDTO> categoryList = categoriesTranslation
        .stream()    
        .map(categoriesAdapter::category2DTO)                
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    categoryList.forEach(dto -> dto.setTotal(
        categoryRepository.countTotalArticlesByCategory(
            categoryDTO.getCategoryId(), languageId
        )
    );
}
```

And for completeness, a mappable version of setting total:

```
void aMethod(Long? languageId) {
    List<CategoryTranslation> categoriesTranslation = categoriesRepository
        .findByLanguageId(languageId);
    List<CategoryDTO> categoryList = categoriesTranslation
        .stream()
        .map(categoriesAdapter::category2DTO)
        .map(x -> setTotal(x, languageId))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

CategoryDTO setTotal(CategoryDTO ctd, Long? languageId) {
    ctd.setTotal(
        categoryRepository.countTotalArticlesByCategory(ctd.getCategoryId(), languageId)
    );
    return ctd;
}
```